# Django 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: django, django-forms

I hope you can see what I'm trying to do here, simply I want to iterate over the values posted for group which look like group = 1,3,5 etc and add them to the database. group is a checkbox. So I wanted to use the split option. I get the following message tho....

**'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'split'**

So it's my understanding it is in the init I use for populating the form which is a query, and I need this but on post it should just be a list. what I'm I doing wrong?

**view.py**

```
form = BatchForm(request.user, request.POST)
        # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
        if form.is_valid():
            # Clean all data and add to var data.
            data = form.cleaned_data
            groups = data['group'].split(",")
            for item in form.cleaned_data['group']:
                batch = Batch(content=data['content'],
                              group=Group.objects.get(pk=item),
                              user=request.user
                              )
                batch.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class BatchForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        exclude = ('user', 'group')



    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            form_choices = Group.objects.for_user(user)
        else:
            form_choices = Group.objects.all()
        self.fields['group'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=form_choices
        )
```

**template.py**

```
{% for value, text in form.group.field.choices %}


    <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="{{ value }}" /> {{text}}<br />

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using the cleaned data and it is a `ModelMultipleChoice` field, it actually is a `queryset`.

Try something like this:

```
form = BatchForm(request.user, request.POST)
    # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
    if form.is_valid():
        # Clean all data and add to var data.
        data = form.cleaned_data
        for group in data['group']:
            batch = Batch(
                content=data['content'],
                group=group,
                user=request.user
            )
            batch.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if form.is_valid():
        # Clean all data and add to var data.
        data = form.cleaned_data
        groups = [x.group for x in form.cleaned_data['group']]
        for item in groups:
            batch = Batch(content=data['content'],
                          group=Group.objects.get(pk=item),
                          user=request.user
                          )
            batch.save()
```